# Ruby keeps reverting to an old version

Tags: rvm

I am having some issues with RVM on Ubuntu. My computer is currently set to dual boot with windows 7 if that matters. I am trying to run the latest version of ruby 1.9.3. Each time I close terminal, it will revert to 1.8.7 despite using rvm use 1.9.3 --default. The following was the steps I was using.

```
michael@michael-Studio-XPS-1640:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
michael@michael-Studio-XPS-1640:~$ rvm use 1.9.3

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

michael@michael-Studio-XPS-1640:~$ /bin/bash --login
michael@michael-Studio-XPS-1640:~$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default
Using /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286
michael@michael-Studio-XPS-1640:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [i686-linux]
```

After I close and reopen the terminal I get the following verion info. I also added the rvm list information as well.

```
michael@michael-Studio-XPS-1640:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]

michael@michael-Studio-XPS-1640:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the displayed instructions:

> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
>   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
>   Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was fixed when I changed those settings inside the preference menu. I thought that the /bin/bash --login would allow for the default to be set.

Comment: it most likely was set already, the `/bin/bash --login` in preferences is required to make it load properly